# Verify paper wallets

Tags: paper-wallet

I generated a paper wallets with offlineaddress.com. Is there a way to check if the private key corresponds to the public key without compromising the wallet by loading it onto an online computer?

Comment: See also [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53564/how-can-i-ensure-private-key-is-valid-on-my-paper-wallet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, only trust highly-reputable software to generate private keys, especially if they're web-based. It seems like this software has only 16 stars on GitHub and only 2 contributors: https://github.com/mikewoods/OfflineAddress.com

To answer your question, the only way to verify that a private key corresponds to the public key is to actually run the algorithm on a computer. My best advice here is to use a computer that is offline and that boots a highly-reputable open source operating system.

Comment: Yes, the addresses have been created with OfflineAddress.com with a live Ubuntu. So import the wallet (on a live system) and see if the private key computes to the public key? Or trust OfflineAddress and safe the hassle?

Comment: Import the private keys into electrum, it will generate the public address to double-check.

Comment: To clarify, reconsider using this service as it's the first I heard of it myself. Even "reputable" services like vanitygen have been compromised such that priv keys are stolen.